# How to properly utilize the definition of e for a specific limit

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have tried to solve the following limit, but I'm stumped.

$\lim_{n \to +\infty} (2-\frac{3}{n})^n$

Is there an effective way to rewrite it? So far, I've rewritten it into

$\lim_{p \to +\infty} ((1-\frac{1}{p})^p)\frac{3}{p-1}$

Where $p=\frac{n}{n-3}$

But what then?

Comment: The limit is not indeterminate, because of the $2$ in the base of the exponent.

Comment: @JoshuaWang What's the difference between having a 2 and a 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the exponential function and the natural logarithm to the general expression as follows: $$\mathrm{e}^{\ln\left(2-\frac{3}{n}\right) ^n},$$ and use the logarithm properties to get the expression $$\lim_{ n \to \infty} \mathrm{e}^{n\ln \left(\frac{(2n-3)}{n}\right)},$$ which diverges positively.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).